# How to Upload files to Puush from Web Server?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I've found a few answers for uploading from outside their official client using cURL in Bash, but I have difficulty transposing it to JavaScript using XMLHttpRequest. The main problem is that I don't think Puush supports CORS. Here's my relevant code thus far:

```
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    fd = new FormData();
xml.open("POST", "http://puush.me/api/up", true);
xml.withCredentials = true; //I've tried with and without this line, neither seems to work
//the following variables are specified from cURL demos I found
fd.append("z", "poop"); //I honestly don't get this part
fd.append("e", "username@domain.com");
fd.append("k", apiKey); //which I copied from my account settings on Puush
fd.append("f", input.files[0]); //where "input" is <input type="file"/>
//add event handlers
xml.addEventListener("progress", progress);
xml.addEventListener("load", loaded);
xml.addEventListener("error", error);
xml.addEventListener("abort", aborted);

xml.send(fd); //send the FormData as a "multipart/form-data" request
```

I always get the same response no matter what I've tried and the error handler always gets called, along with an error log in the console saying that the server did not respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost` (Yes I did not just simply use the file:// protocol, as the null origin was denied as well).

**Edit:** The original bash code can be found at these links:
http://pastebin.com/ZnbY91EA 
https://github.com/nekodex/lazymode/blob/master/puush/puu.sh 
https://github.com/blha303/puush-linux/blob/master/puush 
https://github.com/NickHu/puush-linux/blob/master/puush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the requests actually go through completely, but due to the nature of CORS, the response is rejected. So the files are uploaded but the response throws an error. I've decided to pipe the requests through my server to work around the CORS drawback.